# How can I tether my phone's Wi-Fi connection to a PC over USB?

Tags: wi-fi, motorola-milestone, usb-tethering

Today in my work the people from security are going to block internet access and only admit enterprise local pages. Luckily, there is a free Wi-Fi connection which I have access from my Motorola Milestone. Is there any way for me to tether the Wi-Fi connection over USB to my computer?