# Connect Galaxy S3 Wifi Connection to Computer

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s-3, tethering

I tried googling this, but it kept giving me the USB tethering option, which I don't want.

My laptop currently cannot connect to the Wifi we have at work, because there is a problem with Cisco, Windows 8, and Killer Networks cards not working together.

However, my Galaxy S3 can connect to the Wifi at work perfectly fine.

I know that you can take your phone's mobile data connection, and use that as an internet connection over USB or Wifi.

My question is, if your phone is connected to a Wifi network ALREADY, can you USB tether it to your computer, and use that to connect your computer to the same Wifi network?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't want the USB tethering option, but you're asking if it's OK to USB tether it to your PC? Weird question.

Comment: Okay I'll clarify. I want to connect my phone to my computer via USB so that my computer can share my phone's Wifi connection.  But, I want it to use the Wifi connection that my phone is connected to, NOT my mobile data. And from what I saw on my phone, it only does USB tethering over a mobile network.

Comment: you want to connect to the WiFi network via your phone. yes?

Comment: Yes Sid that's correct.

Comment: Probably not a good solution, but have you tried turning off mobile data while connecting to the WiFi? Would that work?

Comment: I haven't, but I'll try that.  Is there anything else I can try? I heard that turning off the mobile data only works sometimes and not with all phones.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [Can I use my Android device as Wi-Fi Dongle (ie Tethering to PC through USB, but using Wi-FI not Phone Network)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/3134)  or [How can I tether my phone's Wi-Fi connection to a PC over USB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/9929)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just tether and while your phone is connected to the wifi network that connection should be used.
If this is not the case turning off the mobile data should force it to use the wifi connection

Answer (score -2):

Install Kies; it automatically installs all the required drivers. Then, tether to your computer via Wi-Fi hotspot, bluetooth, or USB.

I always use it like that with my S3.